# Is there a rule behind first conjugation verbs ending in -ить?

Tags: грамматика, спряжение

In the book "A comprehensive Russian grammar" by Terence Wade, three different rules are shown for how a first conjugation verb ending in -ить is conjugated. It does not explain when each rule is applicable. Is there a rule for this?

The three examples that are given in the book are:

1. бить: я бью (so the и goes away)
2. брить: я брею (so the и becomes an е)
3. гнить: я гнию (so the и stays)

Answer (score 7):

The ending -ить does not tell you much about how a verb is conjugated. As you've seen, verbs ending in -ить can be conjugated differently. Let me throw in:

- люби́ть - люблю́
- жить - живу́

Note that бре́ю and гнию́ also differ in emphasis.

Moreover, verbs that are conjugated similarly, can have different infinitives:

- брею, бреешь, бреет, INFINITIVE: брить
- грею, греешь, греет, INFINITIVE: греть

Your best bet is to consult a dictionary; e.g. the [Russian Wiktionary](https://w.wiki/4f9h) has conjugation tables for most verbs. As you learn more verbs, you'll learn which ones are conjugated similarly:

- бить, пить, лить - бью, пью, лью,
- любить - люблю, копить - коплю, etc

Andrey Zalizniak's *Grammatical Dictionary of Russian* lists [16 conjugation classes](https://gramdict.ru/conjugation#types), but even those are not comprehensive: some verbs have their own distinct conjugation, e.g. мыть - мо́ю, плыть - плыву́, моло́ть - мелю́ and many others.

Comment: Excellent explanation and excellent English!